# What software can I use to send a USB device over the network from a debian server to a windows client?

Tags: debian, usb, remote, multi-platform, client-server

I have a netbook with not much power, 1GHz CPU & 1G memory.
I'd like to install a headless linux to it, either Debian or TinyCore, both of which use aptitude & dpkg.

I'm not sure which package has a server to run in Debian and a client that can run in Windows to send a USB device on that box over the network to a virtualized Windows environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your windows guests to see the actual USB device, I would recommend [AnywhereUSB](http://www.digi.com/products/usb/anywhereusb.jsp#overview). I've had it in my last two jobs because of the stupid dongle for the alarm management server... Anyway, that's another story.

If you just want to share files off of it, you can use your Linux box to share out via NFS to the VMs...